# admin_notices show after load completed

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

This is my code:

```
class App 
{
    
    public function run()
    {
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'menu']);
        add_action('admin_notices', [$this, 'pip']);
    }

    public function menu()
    {
        echo 0;

        add_submenu_page(
            'tools.php',
            __('Tools', 'name-plugin'),
            __('Name', 'name-plugin'),
            'manage_options',
            'name-plugin',
            [$this, 'show']
        );
    }

    public function show()
    {
        echo 1;
    }

    public function pip() {
        echo 2;
    }
}
```

This code printed `021`

But I want to print `012`

Note: I want to put all `add_action` in `run` method

I used priority too, but it's not work:

```
add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'menu'], 1);
add_action('admin_notices', [$this, 'pip'], 2);
```

If I put `admin_notices` in `show` method, this code works fine.

But I don't want put it in `show` method

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with seeing `021`. I don't know why you'd expect anything different. Admin notices display at the top of the page. That's normal.

Comment: Are you asking how to reposition the notices?

Comment: @JacobPeattie no. I want to show errors from `show` method. But admin_notices run before `show` method and my error not showing

Comment: Are you using the Settings API or something custom? Generally if you have a form in `show()`, the code that handles submission of that form should be in a separate function that's hooked earlier. Then it can pass any errors to the notices hook.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I created it custom

Comment: @JacobPeattie exactly my problem is admin_notice runs before show.

Comment: That does not matter, the order is irrelevant, **if you print out an admin notice further down the page after `admin_notice` has ran, WordPress moves it to the correct position using javascript**. Update your question to include the actual code that tries to add the admin notice, 
_your current theory is incorrect._

Comment: @TomJNowell yes my code is actual. how can I fix it?

Comment: @user212402 Add an actual admin notice instead of just echoing "2".

Comment: @JacobPeattie I added first errors in static variable like $messages = []; after that, i'm echoing $messages

Comment: admin notices aren't just echoing out text on the `admin_notices` hook, they have specific HTML that's needed

Answer (score 0):

Those are not admin notices. It's not enough to `echo` text on the `admin_notices` hook, it needs to be wrapped in specific HTML.

Here is an example taken from [the official WP doc for `admin_notices`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/):

```php
function sample_admin_notice__success() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__success' );
```

If you need to add notices after the hook has fired, use the same HTML structure and WordPress will move it using javascript to the correct place